# Not able to connect nexus 5 to laptop

Tags: root, nexus-5, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have been trying to root my nexus 5 but i am not able to connect it with laptop for that.
It shows my phone there as portable media player
Can anyone tell me how to connect nexus 5 to pc for rooting purpose?

Comment: This question is not about programming and should not be on stackoverflow. Maybe android.stackexchange.com would be a proper place.

Answer (score 0):

If its a Windows laptop try the steps below.

Use a USB cable to connect the Windows PC and your phone .

Open up Device manager.  You'll see the device show up in "Other Devices" as unavailable.

Download and install the Google Generic USB Driver from  http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top .

Note down and remember the location where you install the  google driver to.

Right mouse your device, select Update Driver Software…

Select "Browse for driver software on your computer"

Navigate to where you installed the Google USB Driver software

Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"

Select "Show all devices"

Select "Have Disk"

Navigate to where you installed the Google USB driver, select the android_winusb.inf file

In the Update Driver Software - [your deviced] dialog select "Android ADB Interface"

Ignore the "Update Driver Warning" message.

You will now see the Android Device -> Android ADB Interface in Device Manager, and [your device]  will be gone from "Other Devices". You should now also be able to turn on things like USB/Mass Storage Mode on the phone so you can view files from Windows Explorer as well as debug to the device.

I ran into a similar thing using a BLU VIVO AIR - http://www.devfish.net/post/2015/07/20/android-usb-adb-drivers-for-blu-phones-vivo-air.aspx .

Healy in Tampa

This cost me some serious time. I hope it saves you the time. Frustrating. I love my BLU phones, but their level of support on this was horrible.

“Hate lawyers all you want. Unlike you, we'll never be replaced with robots. Case closed!” ― Amanda Mosher - Better to be loved than lovable ....